# Python - Comparing two sentences, which of these approaches is correct?

Tags: python, arrays, pattern-matching

I am working my way through a python refresher and ran into the following questions which has me a bit stumped regarding how best to answer it. I've place my solution and one I've found online and am interested in seeing which the community thinks is the optimal one, perhaps mine is wrong to begin with:

*Given two sentences, construct an array that has the words that appear in one #sentence and not the other.*

My solution:

```
  A = "Geeks for Geeks"
B = "Learning from Geeks for Geeks"
def findWords(A,B):
    res = []
    asplit = A.split()
    bsplit = B.split()
    #print(asplit)
    #print(bsplit)
    for item in range(len(asplit)):
        if asplit[item] not in bsplit: res.append(asplit[item])

    for item in range(len(bsplit)):
        if bsplit[item] not in asplit: res.append(bsplit[item])

    return res
        
findWords(A,B)
```

Internet Solution:

```
A = "Geeks for Geeks"
B = "Learning from Geeks for Geeks"
d={}
for w in A.split():
    if w in d:
        d[w]=d.get(w,0)+1
    else:
        d[w]=1
for w in B.split():
    if w in d:
        d[w]=d.get(w,0)+1
    else:
        d[w]=1
unmatchedW=[w for w in d if d[w]==1]
print (unmatchedW)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This splits `A` and `B` into words which are stored in a `set()` containing the unique words. The result is equal to the `list` of elements which are different in both sets, namely the symmetric difference between the sets, denoted by the `^` operator.

```
A = "Geeks for Geeks hello"
B = "Learning from Geeks for Geeks"

def findWords(A, B):
    return list(set(A.split(' ')) ^ set(B.split(' ')))

print(findWords(A, B))
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'from', 'Learning']
```

Comment: One possibility that should not be ignored is to use sets.
`sym_diff = set(A.split()) ^ set(B.split())
`

Comment: @Detlef Thanks a lot man. That was really clever.

Comment: The internet solution is a common practice in natural language processing. 
If you only want to filter the duplicates, sets are sufficient.
See also [Document-term matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix).